# How to Lock a Cell on VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Need some help in making a cell edit proof on a Time Stamp, Here is the code I am using :

```
Sub Start()
    Range("A2").Value = Now()
End Sub
```

Basically I don't want an user to have access to edit the time stamp on Cell `A2`. . Any help will be appreciated..Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

What about using Sheet protection?

```
Sub Start()
   'unprotect sheet to edit locked cells'
   ActiveSheet.Unprotect
   'set other cells to be unlocked (I've add this line only because in my excel all cells are locked by defalut, you can delete this line'
   Cells.Locked = False
   'change A2 and make it locked'
   With Range("A2")
       .Value = Now()
       .Locked = True
   End With
   'protect sheet for not allowing change locked cells'
   ActiveSheet.Protect
End Sub
```

Comment: That's a good one..I already tried the Sheet Protection..Here is what I did...


Sub Start()
Sheet1.Protect Password:="Password", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
Range("A2").Value = Now()
End Sub

This will indeed lock the cell..However it does not make the Cell Edit proof rite ? I mean I can manually make the time stamp on Cell "A2" without even running the macro... And when the macro does not run there will not be any protection right ?

Comment: maybe I don't undertand you correctly, but you're not right. Try to call my macro once. You can't manually make the time stamp in `A2` cell, unless you unprotect sheet.